# Running Javascript Off a Webpage Through C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a bunch of webpages where I need to grab some product information but the webpages are all written using javascript. So there will be something like

```
<a href="javascript:__getInfo('content_abc')">Product Name<a>
```

And once that's clicked all the page's content will change (but not the html address). How can I programmatically execute that script and get all the loaded content through a C# script?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. Javascript runs client side (unliess you're using something like node.js) while C#/ASP.net runs serverside. You need something to bridge the gap like AJAX and webservices.

Answer (score 0):

While this is the wrong approach to your problem, there is a solution that might work.

By using automated testing tools, such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp), it is possible to use the web driver interface to take control of a web browser and interact with elements on the screen, click buttons and check for results.